# WARNING: Callback failed: aura://ComponentController/ACTION$getApplication while embedding Lightning app into nodejs

Tags: node.js

on salesforce side done this work

1)  CORS Whitelist Origin  set to https://*.herokuapp.com.

2)  on sandbox created App dxTest2App

```
  <aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <c:dxTest2 />   
 </aura:application> 

created Component dxTest2 

 <aura:component access="GLOBAL">
            Hello
 </aura:component>
```

On origin Server node js side done this work 
i have passed oauth.access_token after authentication in index.js file of nodejs.
In Index.hjs work to load Lightning app is done.

•   for this purpose i have included
       
•   created script

```
  The function setupLightning() is called in index.hjs is created in app.js .All needed code for loading done in this.
```

index.hjs is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>TouchCR</title>   
   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">   
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="setupLightning();">
  <form>
    <input name="Token" Id="Token" type="hidden" value="{{oauth.access_token}}"/>

  <div id="messages" style="background: lightblue; height: 400px; width: 400px;></div>
     <div id="future"></div>
    <script src="XXXXXXmy.salesforce.com/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascripts/app.js"></script>
    </form>
  </body>  
</html>
```

app.js code is :-

```
function setupLightning() {

    var oauth_token = document.getElementById('Token').value;   
    var url   = 'https://mcnabb--devsanbox.lightning.force.com';

    $Lightning.use("c:dxTest2App", function() {

         $Lightning.createComponent("c:dxTest2",
         { label : " Comp" },
         "lightning");
       }, url, oauth_token);    
}
```

Here is code for loading App in function setupLightning.but i have got this warning while loading component.

> WARNING: Callback failed: aura://ComponentController/ACTION$getApplication

Comment: Any resolution on this even am getting error  `WARNING: Callback failed: aura://ComponentController/ACTION$getApplication  `

Comment: Usually when they are completely and totally vague like this it's some form of bad syntax and lightning gives the horribly vague message. What I do is examine the most recently edited code for syntax problems. I've gotten this when i used a : instead of a ; to terminate a line of code. and many other syntax errors. Another thing I do is in recently edited code put a system.log('made it here'); message and check the console log. then move it a couple lines down and do it again. when the message no longer appears in the console log you no know what lines of code it doesn't like

Answer (score 0):

You have to add aura:dependency to both App and Component.

Comment: Please also show how to add it to the code as well as putting in the short answer - see [answer]. Thanks.